# Password protect nginx without root access

Tags: nginx

I have non-root ssh access to a server running nginx. How can I password protect a directory (similar to `.htaccess` with Apache) without having root access to the configuration files in `/etc/nginx/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: You can't. `nginx` has no equivalent to the user configuration with `.htaccess` files because  the devs decided this is wrong and haven't heard of the possibility to make this optional. 
 https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/likeapache-htaccess/

Comment: Thank you for confirming what I suspected. Since the user's web pages are all in PHP, I have instructed him to use some PHP-based password protection, which we both agreed is "good enough" in this particular use case.